# time complexity and geometric series, nested loops

Tags: loops, time-complexity, big-o

I have the following code and i am trying to understand what is its time complexity:

```
for (int i = 1 ; i <= n ; i = i*2)
    for (int j = 1 ; j <= n ; j = j*2)
        for (int k = 1 ; k <= j ; k++)
```

What I did was:
the first loop runs log n times, the second loop also runs log n times and the third loop is a geometric series

so overall I have the running time will be: `n*(log(n))^2`

Is this correct?
thank you!

Comment: Almost. There is only one factor of `log(n)` in the correct answer - can you see why?

Comment: is it because i use the 2nd loop when i calculate the geomatric series of the third loop?  n=log n, q=2,a=1..

Comment: Not sure what `n=log n, q=2,a=1` are but yes, the number of times the third loop runs increases geometrically – 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, ..., n – the sum of which is bounded by 2n.

Comment: the sum of a geometric series is a1 * (q^n -1) / q-1. here q=2 and n=log n.. so overall it is n-1.. but dont  i have to multiply it twice by log n?

Comment: No, only once for the outer loop because it is independent from the other two. The geometric series arises from the coupling of the inner and middle loops, not just the inner loop itself.

Answer (score -1):

By theory you are correct the complexity is `n*(log(n))^2`.

For Practical Lets iterate for n=1000:

```
i = 1; n= 1000; j= 1;k =1; result = 0
while i<=n:
    j=1
    while j<=n:
        k=1
        while k<=j:
            result = result+1
            k = k+1
        j = j*2
    i = i*2
print(result)
```

and we get result = 10230

so the actual value of result we get using the `floor(logn)+1) * (2 ^ floor(logn)+1) - 1)` formula. For n=1000 it is 10*(2^10-1)

For n=2^25
we get result 1744830438 which also satisfies using the formula= 26*((2^26)-1) = 1744830438.

Comment: check your solution for n = 2^25 :/

Comment: @MortezaJalambadani edited and added for 2^25, can you bring more light about which case you are referring to? thanks though for bringing this up.

Comment: what is diffrence between **`(floor(logn)+1) - 1`** and **`floor(logn)`** ?

Comment: Let x = floor(logn)+1  Then the formula would be x * ((2^x) -1) .So the subtraction would be from the result of power 2. I am editing with more braces to clarify the precedence in calculation.